# How can i use inline css in CodeIgniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, url

i want to add a banner image .

```
 <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('Style/images/banner/banner.jpg');">
```

how can i use this in CodeIgniter file

i tried

```
<div class="slide" style="background-image: url('<?php echo base_url()?>/Style/images/banner/banner.jpg');">
```

Comment: seems right to me.. but the paths are different.. check what does `base_url()` gives you.. to debug just copy the url produce and paste it on your browser.. I think it's 404 coz the first snippet is relative and in codeigniter is absolute, so better check your image directory

Comment: make sure `Style` `S` is caps in folder name

Comment: Yes . S   is  caps :(

Comment: can you add folder structure??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

`style="background-image: url('<?php echo base_url('Style/images/banner/banner.jpg') ?>')"`

Answer (score 1):

You can just do like this. **No need to use `base_url()`**

```
<div class="slide" 
style="background-image: url('Style/images/banner/banner.jpg');">
```

> **Make sure your folder call `Style`'s first letter is capitalized.**

---

**EDIT 01**

> > **Provide  permeation  to image**

```
goto project root
cd Style/images/banner/
sudo ^Cmod -R 777 banner.jpg
```

Comment: check image permition

Comment: @AbySebastian did you check this??

Comment: not that OC but just want to correct `permition` should be `permission`

Answer (score 1):

You can use internal css in view file, check below example.

```
<style>
.slide{
  background-image: url('<?php echo base_url()>/Style/images/banner/banner.jpg');
}
</style>
```